# Passing string in flask

Tags: python, string, flask, parameter-passing

I have the following problem and can't seem to find an answer for it, even though I assume it's fairly straight forward...

I am trying to pass a string in Python/flask from one function to another. 
Without flask this works and prints my text.

```
[...]
def sample(args):
    with open(os.path.join(args.save_dir, 'config.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        saved_args = cPickle.load(f)
    with open(os.path.join(args.save_dir, 'chars_vocab.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        chars, vocab = cPickle.load(f)
    model = Model(saved_args, training=False)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(args.save_dir)
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
            text = model.sample(sess, chars, vocab, args.n, args.prime,
                               args.sample).encode('utf-8')
            printer(text)

def printer(text):    
    print(text)
```

This works fine and prints my string.
If I try to implement flask I get an Internal Servor Error on 127.0.0.1:5000/text

```
def sample(args):
    with open(os.path.join(args.save_dir, 'config.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        saved_args = cPickle.load(f)
    with open(os.path.join(args.save_dir, 'chars_vocab.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        chars, vocab = cPickle.load(f)
    model = Model(saved_args, training=False)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(args.save_dir)
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
            text = model.sample(sess, chars, vocab, args.n, args.prime,
                               args.sample).encode('utf-8')
            printer(text)

@app.route('/text')
def printer(text):    
    return(text)
```

If I just try to display some text without passing a string it works fine.

I'm completely new to python and flask, I would greatly appreciate any help!

here's the Traceback from the Terminal:

```
 [2017-12-02 15:47:06,244] ERROR in app: Exception on /text [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marcel/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/marcel/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/marcel/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/marcel/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/marcel/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/marcel/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: printer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
```

Comment: Can you post the entire traceback (as an edit to you question). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the console output of the terminal where you run the flask app.
It should have the stack trace with details to debug,
probably ending in a line like this:

> ```
> TypeError: printer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
> ```

The problem is that the functions decorated with `@app.route` are called without parameters, but the `printer` function you defined is expecting one. You need to make the function parameterless:

```
@app.route('/text')
def printer():    
    # ...
```

And you need to change its implementation so that it returns a valid `Response` object.
See the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/) for examples.

Comment: Yeah you're right, that's the exact error. I'm looking into the Response object. Thank you!